# Determining HTML Element in a web page for web scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

Here is the HTML code:

```
 <span class="milestone">Announcement:</span>
 "&nbsp; 2 April 2000 "
 <br>
 <span class="milestone">Ground Breaking:</span>
 "&nbsp; 23 February 2002
 <br>
 etc.
```

On the web page, I can see:

**Announcement:** 2 April 2000

**Ground Breaking:** 23 February 2002

But I cannot figure out how to grab the dates using Python's BeautifulSoup.  I can see the date information when using Chrome's "inspect element," but I can't figure out the HTML element necessary to grab it.  Is there a nuance with `&nbsp;` that makes scraping more difficult?  I'm not sure what options to explore next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `BeautifulSoup` this is relatively straightforward - the idea is to locate the "milestone" elements by class and text and then get to the next sibling using [`.next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<div>
 <span class="milestone">Announcement:</span>
 "&nbsp; 2 April 2000 "
 <br>
 <span class="milestone">Ground Breaking:</span>
 "&nbsp; 23 February 2002 "
 <br>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

print(soup.find(class_="milestone", text="Announcement:").next_sibling.strip())
print(soup.find(class_="milestone", text="Ground Breaking:").next_sibling.strip())
```

Prints:

```
"  2 April 2000 "
"  23 February 2002 "
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed.  Is .next_sibling part of the BeautifulSoup library?

Comment: @mschmidt yup, it is a built-in method, glad it helped.